# Nullable JOINCOLUMN field transient exception Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullable, joincolumn

I am working with `spring` `hibernate` project where a model has a `foreign key` which mapped with `@joincolumn` as shown below.

```
class Customer
{
@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_RM_ID",nullable=true)
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private RmSm customerRMId;
}
```

But, while saving this entity from angular js UI, via rest api, i am getting below mentioned exception.

Request:

```
  {"customerRMId":{
    "id":null
    }
}
```

I have removed all other fields from the model and the request as well, for the readability purpose.

Exception:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:

What is the solution for this, I have tried with hibernate `nullable` true option. But didn't work!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with that field. Is there any other fields that hold reference to other entities? is any of these fields populated with a transient object (not yet saved to db, id is null and version is null)

Comment: @YazanJaber no its because of this field only. When i give a value insetad of null it works .

Comment: Try to add cascade option in @OneToOne, like this one cascade = CascadeType.ALL or SAVE_UPDATE or PERSIST. Depending on your task